# Is this way of finding the expectation of a random variable involving a Brownian motion correct?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I have the following stochastic process:

$X(t)=e^{-t}W(e^{2t})$

Where $W(t)$ is a Brownian motion and $t\in[0,\infty)$. Now consider the following process:

$Y(t)=\int_{0}^{t}X(s)ds$

Can we then calculate the expectation as follows?

$\mathbb{E}[Y(t)]=\int_{0}^{t}\mathbb{E}[e^{-s}W(e^{2s})]ds=\int_{0}^{t}e^{-s}\mathbb{E}[W(e^{2s})]ds=\int_{0}^{t}e^{-s}0ds$=0

Or have I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: It is correct. There are no mistakes.

Comment: why can you interchange $\int$ and $\mathbb E$?

Comment: Isn't the expectation of an integral with respect to t is equal to the integral of the expectation?

Comment: In this case you can interchange the integrals, but you must justify it. In general it doesn't hold!